# What are "nonremovable row versions"?

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I did full vacuum on postgresql-9.4 database and I have a lot of tables with nonremovable row versions. I would like to know what are these or where I can read about them.

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.profile_generals"
INFO:  "profile_generals": found 0 removable, 654 nonremovable row versions in 51 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
```

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are your data. You probably don't want to remove them ;)

"nonremovable row versions" includes the current, active row versions containing the data you care about. It also includes row versions made obsolete by a delete or update, but still visible to the snapshot of one or more running transactions.

You should only be concerned if there are lots of nonremovable *dead* row versions. That is not the case here. To learn more, read the manual on [routine vacuuming](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html), the chapter on concurrency and MVCC, and read about table bloat.